# Linear ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am struggling with the following ODE: $$
y''(x)+2\mathrm{tanh}(x)y'(x)+\big(1-2\mathrm{sech}^2(x)\big)y(x)=0, \qquad y(0)=1, \quad y'(0)=0.
$$
As you can see this is a second-order **linear** ODE with variable coefficients. I am wondering if it is possible to explicitly solve it, and what would be its solution. My first thought was that maybe I could use Laplace's transform but it seems extremely hard to do it (and I am not sure how to do it neither if it is possible). Is there any "good" way to approach it?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

By changing $\tanh x=z$ this equation can be tranformed to Legendre ODE
The total solution would be like:
$$y=f(z)[C_1 P_\nu(z)+C_2 Q_\nu(z)]$$
where $\nu$ and $f(z)$ can then be determines.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, just one question: How do you deal then with the unknown? I mean, you will get something like $y(\mathrm{arctanh}(x))$, so it is not very easy to combine standard ODE techniques with an unknown evaluated at something very strange

Comment: @Sharrik one tires to trabsform such ODEs with variable coefficient into four/five well known equations (Legendre here) other wise most of them are not solvable, Just now I find that mathematica gives: $\nu=(-1+i\sqrt{7})/2, f(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}$

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about this procedure of obtaining four/five ODEs? I would really appreciate it